# How to remove extra zeros

Tags: c, xcode

Sorry for the basic question, I just started learning C.

This is the output I'm trying to get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6D30.png

This is what I'm currently getting:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yoSQ.png

How do I get rid of the extra three zeros at the end of my Batting Average?

My code:

```
#include <string.h>

//structure
struct Stats {
    char player [20];
    double bat_avg;
    unsigned int hr;
    unsigned int rbi;
};

//function prototypes
void printHeader();

//begin of main
int main(void)
{
    int return_value = 0;
    struct Stats player_1, player_2, player_3;

    //player 1
    strcpy(player_1.player, " Kurt");
    player_1.bat_avg = 0.350;
    player_1.hr = 40;
    player_1.rbi = 123;

    //player 2
    strcpy(player_2.player, " Jenny");
    player_2.bat_avg = 0.321;
    player_2.hr = 4;
    player_2.rbi = 56;

    //player 3
    strcpy(player_3.player, " Amanda");
    player_3.bat_avg = 0.281;
    player_3.hr = 15;
    player_3.rbi = 76;

    //print the heading
    printHeader();

    //print rows of statistics
    printf("%s%26f%3u%u\n", player_1.player, player_1.bat_avg, player_1.hr, player_1.rbi);
    printf("%s%25f%3u%u\n", player_2.player, player_2.bat_avg, player_2.hr, player_2.rbi);
    printf("%s%24f%3u%u\n", player_3.player, player_3.bat_avg, player_3.hr, player_3.rbi);

}//end of main
//BEGIN of printHeader
void printHeader() {
    printf(" Player Name   Batting Avg.  HR   RBI\n");
    printf("======================================\n");
}
//END of printHeader
```

Comment: Don't put random language tags in your questions, and please read this from [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_"

Comment: As a newcomer to Stack Overflow, please also make sure that if an answer (or multiple answers) is acceptable to you, you mark it as accepted. This will help others browsing through existing questions to see that an answer is there which is worth looking at.

Answer (score 2):

Use a decimal point in your format specifier, followed by a number, to specify the number of digits to be printed after  the decimal point.

Example: `%.3f`

Answer (score 2):

While you should not include pictures of code or text input/output rather than just text in your post, the solution to your problem is to use field width specifiers.

Your already using them to specify the overall width, but you can further modify your `%24f` format specifier to say how many digits you're like after the decimal point: `%24.3f`.

You'll find a good reference for these format specifiers [at cppreference.com](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).